# How to reflect on method with out params?

Tags: c#, reflection, out-parameters

I am trying to get a `MethodInfo` object for a method on a type with an `out` param in its signature. Something to the effect of this:

```
MethodInfo tryParse = typeof(T).GetMethod(
    "TryParse",
    BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static,
    null,
    new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(T) },
    null);
```

But the problem is, it doesn't find it because the type of the second parameter is not simply `T` but `out T`. When I debug through and use `typeof(T).GetMethods()` I can see the actual `MethodInfo` that I want and the `ParameterInfo` object is either of type `T&` or `T ByRef`, but I can't see how to create the `Type` that represents this from `typeof(T)`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

And the very next thing anyone with this question is going to run into is "Okay but how to I invoke it!?!" [This article](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/29/145767.aspx) cleared that up for me. Short answer: the arguments array contains the out param, not the variable you used to populate the arguments array.